# How do I solve this nonlinear equation using lambert w function?

Tags: nonlinear-analysis

I have been trying to solve this nonlinear equation for sometime now to no avail. I have tried Mathematica and matlab as well. But I believe that a solution exist in terms of x (probably using the Lambert W function).
This is the equation below.

$b\cdot x^a+d\cdot \ln(1+c\cdot x)+\ln(1+(e^p-1)\cdot (1-u))/p=0$

Please, I will be grateful if the symbolic solution is in term of x.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think such a solution for $x$ is possible here, since you have $1+x^c$ instead of $x^c$, which is manageable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution to this problem in a closed form. Choose $a=c$ and you will get a closed form.

Comment: Ok Seyhmus. I will try a=c. Thanks a lot.